# Acumatica WebAPI: How to get Kit Component Information from the Detail Line of a Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I've been trying to find the corresponding Kit Component information using information from SO301000 SalesOrder.DocumentDetails. So far I've found out that I can get the component details of a specific revision from IN209500 KitSpecifications using the InventoryID along with the revisionID. The problem is that I'm unsure how to find the Kit Revision information using information from the SalesOrder DocumentDetail line. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to tackle this situation, so if someone could kindly direct me to the next step, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Acumatica, Stock Kits are considered like any other regular product. When a stock kit is sold, one line item appears in the transaction and the on-hand quantity of the kit is reduced - there is no option to see what was the Kit Revision of just sold Stock Kit.

Non-stock kits are not stocked and can be added to a sales order requesting them without preliminary assembly. When a non-stock kit is listed on a sales order as a line item, its stock components are specified on a pick list and shipped to the customer. Upon shipment confirmation, the quantity of stock components is decreased while the quantities of non-stock components and kits are not tracked in any way. Since Acumatica does not allow having more then 1 active Kit Specification for a Non-Stock Kit, the components are always chosen based on the only active specification.

To access components of a Non-Stock Kit, one should first create Shipment for a Sales Order, after that list of Kit Components is available on the Allocations popup:
[image]

Comment: Just to add to this question, if I had multiple active Stock Kits with the same Stock Components but varying Non-Stock Components, would there be a way for me to find what the Non-Stock Components used for a given order is? Or is that impossible because the Non-Stock Components are not tracked in any way. Also is it poor practice to have a Stock Kit that includes Non-Stock Components.

Comment: If you had multiple active Stock Kits with the same Stock Components but varying Non-Stock Components, there would not be any option to find what the Non-Stock Components used due to use of Stock Kits. There is nothing wrong in having a Stock Kit that includes Non-Stock Components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer